# Multiple PayPal buttons inside single Form Element

Tags: php, forms, paypal

Currently I can have single paypal button in a form element like:

```
<form id="pkg1" name="_xclick" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

                    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="seller_1360303883_biz@gmail.com"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Digital Download"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="$<?php  echo $price1 ?>"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/success.php"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="notify.php"/>
                    <input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!"/>

                </form>
```

I wonder if there is a way to place more than one paypal buttons in single form??
I'm no talking about adding to cart.
So is there a way that i be able to make individual transactions while putting them in single form?

Thanx in Advance

Comment: Could you clarify your question? It doesn't seem to make any sense. If you want multiple separate transactions, then they need to be separate forms (the forms contain the dollar amounts, transaction IDs, etc). If you want multiple buttons for the same transaction - sure, just copy the `<input type="image"...` around.

Comment: @ Colin Morelli: Thanx for paying attention
Actually i want to perform multiple separate transactions in a single form.
So is this possible?
Or adding to cart is the only way?

Comment: @ leftclickben:Thanx man for your time.
 Currently i am using separate forms for separate transactions.

Comment: Separate form is the best way to do it.